# MediaManager api not working on android phone

Tags: codenameone

when i got to know of the mediamanager api I used it to create a video player just as it was said the tutorial. It runs on the simulator but does not work on my phone.
What do you think is the problem.My Computer runs with a Windows 8 Pro and I tried the app on x-tigi phone and tablet. I got the code from a pdf named **Codename One Developer Guide** This is the code:

```
final Form hi = new Form("MediaPlayer", new BorderLayout());
hi.setToolbar(new Toolbar());
Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Title");
FontImage icon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_VIDEO_LIBRARY, s);
hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("", icon, (evt) -> {
  Display.getInstance().openGallery((e) -> {
  if(e != null && e.getSource() != null) {
  String file = (String)e.getSource();
  try {
  Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(file, true);
  hi.removeAll();
  hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new MediaPlayer(video));
  hi.revalidate();
  } catch(IOException err) {
  Log.e(err);
  }
  }
  }, Display.GALLERY_VIDEO);
});
hi.show();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Can you add the code you used and point to the specific tutorial? Please also specify which device type/OS version as that matters a lot. FYI you can press edit next to your question to edit it and then comment here so I'll get a notification that the question changed

Comment: Sorry but I think I have edited it